# logic error in yii2 when save to database

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, logic

the below coding might have logic error which I cannot identify since I'm not so good in logic.

```html
public function actionSave()
   {  
      //initiate connection
        $request = Yii::$app->request;

        if (Yii::$app->request->post())
        {
            //receive from POST, insert into $student
            $student=Yii::$app->request->post('sudent');


           //receive from POST, insert into $selection
           $selection=Yii::$app->request->post('selection');

            //looping foreach and set  $student as $key
          foreach ($student as $key => $value) 
          {                    
               if($key==0 )
               {

                 $check=$selection[$key];
                }

              elseif($key)
              {

                 $check=empty($selection[$key])?'':$selection[$key];

              }

              else{
                 //don't know what to do here
            }


              $model=new Attendance();
              if($check || $check==0)
              {

              $model->student_id=$value;
              $model->attendance_check=1;
              $model->attendance_date=time();
              // $model->attendance_reason=$value;
              $model->save();
              }

              else
              {
              $model->student_id=$value;
              $model->attendance_check=0;
              $model->attendance_date=time();
              // $model->attendance_reason=$value;
              $model->save();
              }
            }   
        } 
        else 
        {
           //don't know what to do here

        }

   }
```

the flow is, when this controller receive from POST (checked box and some texfields) it will go to foreach and check if the checkbox==1 (means it is ticked) it wil insert to databse. if not, still insert into database but with value 0.

one from 7 checkbox i did not tick. so, in database 6 attendance_check will hold value 1 and 1 attendance_check hold value 0.

what i get? all hold value 1.

what are the error?

Thanks.

--update 22/3/2016--

the form view (named index.php)

```html
<?php

use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvide;
use yii\grid\CheckboxColumn;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;

//active form start
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    //send to 'key-in-attendance/save'
    'action' => Url::to(['key-in-attendance/save']),
]) ?>


    
  <?php

        
        //keluarkan grifview
  echo GridView::widget([

     'dataProvider' =>$dataProvider,
     
     'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


        'id',
        'student_name',
        'class_id',

        //checkbox untuk kehadiran
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        'checkboxOptions'=>['style'=>'display: block;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;'],
        'header' => Html::checkBox('selection_all', false, [
            'class' => 'select-on-check-all pull-right',
          'label' => '<span class="pull-left">Check Attend Only</span>',//pull left the label
        ]),

        'checkboxOptions' => function ($data, $key, $index, $column) 
        {
            return ['value' => $index];
        }
        ],


        //text box utk masukkan sebab tak hadir
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn', 
            'label'=> 'Reason not attend',
            'value' => function ($data) 
            {
                return Html::textarea("reason".$data->id); 
            },
            'format'=>'raw'
        ],


        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn', 
            'value' => function ($data) 
            {
                return Html::hiddeninput("sudent[]",$data->id); 
            },
            'format'=>'raw'
        ],



     ],
  ]); 
  ?>

        <!-- butang submit dan tutup active form -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

--update 23/3/2016--

[image: selection that I make]
selection that I made

[image: in the database]
in the database

Comment: it may not be a logical error but 'just' a typo ?
`$student=Yii::$app->request->post('s**t**udent');` (missing 't' in 'sudent')

Comment: `if ($check || $check == 0) {` i think this condition includes all possible scenarios (which has `$model->attendance_check = 1;`) . Can't say more without seeing the form elements.

Comment: @Stan not typo. it use $sudent from view..

Comment: @Stan i have included in update form view (namedindex.php)

Comment: @ck_arjun i have included in update form view (name dindex.php)

Comment: Can you also show the post data you get after submit .By leaving some checkbox unchecked.

Comment: @ck_arjun updated with image as requested

Answer (score 0):

Select is already going to be indexed by the ID of your data provider, so the sudent array is unnecessary.

The following should work.

```
public function actionSave()
{  
  //initiate connection
    $request = Yii::$app->request;

    if (Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
       //receive from POST, insert into $selection
       $selection=Yii::$app->request->post('selection');

        //looping foreach and set  $student as key
      foreach ($selection as $value => $check) 
      {                    


          $model=new Attendance();
          $model->student_id=$value;
          $model->attendance_check=$check ? 1 : 0;
          $model->attendance_date=time();
          // $model->attendance_reason=$value;
          $model->save();
        }   
    } 
    else 
    {
       //don't know what to do here

    }
}
```

One more thing to consider is that you are creating new Attendance records but responses might already have been recorded, you want to load first.

```
  $model = Attendance::findOne(['student_id'=>$value]);
  if(!$model) $model = new Attendance();
```